# Apache Reverse Proxy to URL With Parameters

Tags: apache, url, parameters, proxy, reverse

I am trying to setup a reverse proxy with 2 CentOS 6.5 machines running Apache 2.2.15, where the **private** URL contains parameters (static, same for all requests coming through the public url), so the setup should work like this:

**User --> public.url/ --> private.url/?parameter=value**

**User --> public.url/anything --> private.url/anything?parameter=value**

I have managed to setup the reverse proxy using the following directives in /etc/httpd/conf.d/reverse-proxy.conf

```
    ProxyRequests Off

    proxyPass / private.url:80/ connectiontimeout=5 timeout=30
    proxyPassReverse / private.url:80/

    ProxyPassReverseCookieDomain private.url public.url

    <Location />

            RequestHeader unset Accept-Encoding
            AddOutputFilterByType SUBSTITUTE text/html
            Substitute "s|private.url|public.url|i"

    </Location>
```

and everything works as expected:

**User --> public.url/ --> private.url/**

**User --> public.url/anything --> private.url/anything**

however I am not sure how to accomplish the addition of the **?parameter=value** suffix to the private.url

Any fingers pointing in the right direction will be much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I eventually got it to work the way I wanted with mod_rewrite

```
    #Check if string already exists
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(.*parameter.*) [NC]
    #Add the string and keep hidden from user with [P]
    RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ public.url/$1?parameter=value [P]
```

Hope someone else finds this useful

Comment: does it go within the location tag?

Answer (score 1):

reminder: it does not work in location context according to documentation https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule