# Pass Multiple Parameters From Redirect URL In Apache Proxy Reverse

Tags: apache, laravel-echo

I'm running an app that utilizes [laravel-echo-server](https://github.com/tlaverdure/laravel-echo-server). So for me to run it on my production server over `https` I need to use apache proxy reverse to redirect my `/tools/socket.io/` urls to `http://localhost:6001`.

While that is working fine I keep getting this error `Cannot Post /` because I need to pass along the params from my domain url to my reverse proxy url.
Here is my apache config:

```
ProxyPreserveHost On
ProxyRequests off
ProxyPass /tools/socket.io/ http://localhost:6001/
ProxyPassReverse /tools/socket.io/ http://localhost:6001/
```

I came across this post [stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28558357/apache-reverse-proxy-to-url-with-parameters) but the implementation didn't work for me.

So this are the parameters I need to pass and their values are dynamic `EIO` `transport` `t`. and my url is like

`https://exampledomain.com/tools/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=Ml8lZDJ`

Comment: Instead of `ProxyPass`, use `RewriteRule` with parameter `QSA`.  http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule

Comment: thanks i've gotten it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my apaxhe config within my SSL virtualhost for my domain:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/socket.io            [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} transport=websocket    [NC]
RewriteRule /(.*)           ws://localhost:6001/$1 [P,L]

ProxyPass        /socket.io http://localhost:6001/socket.io
ProxyPassReverse /socket.io http://localhost:6001/socket.io
```